# CloudFormation for SNS HTTPS subscription with password from SecretsManager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I need help creating a CloudFormation script (yaml) for https SNS subscription.

The endpoint requires authentication with basic auth credentials, which are stored in AWS Secrets Manager. The password contains special characters, which, in my opinion, should be URL encoded before being placed in the URL.

The following syntax works if the password doesn't contain any special characters:

```
UmApiSubscription:
Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
Properties:
  Protocol: https
  Endpoint: !Sub 'https://{{resolve:secretsmanager:/foo/bar:SecretString:username}}:{{resolve:secretsmanager:/foo/bar-api:SecretString:password}}@my-domain.com/api/endpoint-name'
  TopicArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:12345678:my-topic-name'
```

I need a tip how to URL encode the password within CloudFormation script.
An ugly workaround would be to add the secret key `urlEncodedPassword` but I'd like to avoid it as much as possible.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!